# Set specific colors in a line plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

I have 6 different columns in my dataset (cum_return_pf) which are plotted in a graph (see below). The resulting 6 lines all have a random color.

How can I set the colors of each line by my own? I need that, because I want to have always the same colors in different plots

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = cum_return_pf.plot(figsize=(10, 5))
ax.set(xlabel="Year", ylabel="Return") 
plt.savefig('Comparison.jpg', dpi=300)
```

This produces:

[image: Graph]

Comment: The colours are not random, they are using the default 'cycler'. You can [make your own](You want the colour cycler https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/color_cycle.html). Is the problem that the number of lines keeps changing, or maybe the order of your data? Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Similar as the suggestion to use the `cycler`, you could also define a list with colors (e.g. from a [Colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)), where each row corresponds to the color for each plot.

**Using a qualitative colormap**

```
#list with 5 colors, e.g. from colormap 'tab10'
c = [plt.cm.tab10(i) for i in range(5)]
```

**Using a non-qualitative colormap**

```
#list with 5 colors
c = [plt.cm.RdBu_r(i/5) for i in range(5)]
```

**Complete example**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#some random data
numLines = 5
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, numLines)))

#list with colors
c = [plt.cm.RdBu_r(i/numLines) for i in range(numLines)]

#plot
ax = df.plot(color=c)
plt.show()
```